# Use of NVIDIA graphics driver hangs computer

Tags: drivers, nvidia, crash, gpu-driver

A while ago, I added the `graphics-drivers` PPA and installed the 415 driver. I decided to go back to my original driver, the 390, but seemingly made a mistake in doing so - I removed the PPA before switching. When I tried to switch from the 415 to the 390, I got an error message (I don't recall the exact message, but it mentioned cache).

When using the 390 driver, I cannot have NVIDIA prime-selected. If I do, I find that:

- My system cannot cannot boot to the desktop properly, instead getting stuck in a short cycle between the Ubuntu loading logo and a terminal flooded with the following, repeated over and over, before ending with a black screen:

> Starting NVIDIA persistence daemon
>
> Stopping NVIDIA persistence daemon

- Use of certain NVIDIA tools causes the screen to hang. For example, if I use `nvidia-settings`, the screen freezes. If I use `nvidia-bug-report.sh`, the system freezes having only generated the following `nvidia-bug-report.log.gz`:

.

```
____________________________________________

Start of NVIDIA bug report log file.  Please include this file, along
with a detailed description of your problem, when reporting a graphics
driver bug via the NVIDIA Linux forum (see devtalk.nvidia.com)
or by sending email to 'linux-bugs@nvidia.com'.

nvidia-bug-report.sh Version: 23805530

Date: Wed 27 Feb 02:08:52 GMT 2019
uname: Linux u-rdm 4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 14:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
command line flags:
```

When I run `lspci -v`, the graphics related entries seem to be the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 620
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 142
    Memory at d2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at d3000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

If I run `glxinfo`, there is no reference to NVIDIA. It seems to go with the integrated graphics:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
```

When the issue first occured, I recall trying to purge and re-install the NVIDIA packages, to no avail.

I notice that, running `lsmod`, there is no appearance of the `nvidiafb` module mentioned by `lspci`. Also, running `sudo modprobe nvidia` yields the following causes the system to hang.

Currently, `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` gives me the following output:

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                 390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                  390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                 390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                  390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                    390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                     390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                      390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                    390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-390                          390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                   390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                           390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390              390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

The result of `dkms status` is the following:

```
nvidia, 390.77, 4.18.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed
```

The content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is shown here: https://pastebin.com/wBr470Cx

**EDIT:**

Going into `/var/log/syslog`, I've noticed some error outputs. Firstly, the following was printed:

```
Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 123 has read and write permissions for those files.
```

This seems to be reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/1611635). To fix this, I assigned ownership of `/dev/nvidia*` to the `nvidia-persistenced` group, which worked. That particular error went away, but the following was still present:

```
The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
```

I found the solution for that [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/720). Restarting after fixing this, with `prime-select nvidia`, the boot got stuck on the "Started User MAnager for UID 121" stage.

Currently, I note I can run `nvidia-settings` without issue, but get the following output:

```
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
have been installed along with this driver at 
/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

I fixed the registry file error by copying `/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-<version info>-key-documentation` to `/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation`, but the `Missing Extension` errors remainded. Next, I ran `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`, added the graphics-drivers PPA, `apt update`d and installed `nvidia-390`. Now, the only error on using `nvidia-settings` is:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

Running `nvidia-bug-report.sh` at this point no longer hangs the laptop, but the file generated is the same (no information above the horizontal line).

Comment: Run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`

Comment: Now it looks better. Restart and it should work.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the advice. The change was due to me mistakenly uploading a dpkg output which was based off of the open source 390 driver, rather than the priorietary one.

Comment: There is no "open source 390 driver". Does it work now?

Comment: No, unfortunately not: it still results in the terminal spam and following black screen. Re-running the tests with the correct driver selected, `sudo modprobe nvidia` now produces `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': No such device`.

Comment: Please post output of `dkms status`.

Comment: I've added it to the post. I also updated the result of `lspci`, whose output has also changed (I specifically noticed different kernel modules listed than before). If it's of relevance, I am using `prime-select nvidia` for these tests (which seems fine so long as I don't use any NVIDIA tools, otherwise I get the mentioned freeze).

Comment: Re-install the driver. `sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*' && sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`. I see driver versions don't match.

Comment: Re-installed and restarted: the previous symptoms are still present, but `dpkg` shows a consistent version now. Also, the result of `sudo modprobe nvidia` has changed, and it now hangs the system instead of reporting that the device wasn't found.

Comment: what does `prime-select query` show?

Comment: For testing I've been setting `sudo prime-select nvidia`, so `prime-select query` just shows `nvidia`. When the system hangs, I have to enter recovery and `prime-select intel` to get it to boot again, but I set it back when it boots up for running the commands. If I run `sudo modprobe nvidia` with `sudo prime-select intel` set, I get output corresponding with that in the following bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1774359

Comment: The driver is installed properly. I have no more ideas.

Comment: One more. Are you sure Secure Boot is disabled?

Comment: Yeah - a message also popped up during the driver re-installation process mentioning the fact, and the process seemed to go successfully.

Comment: Go to BIOS settings and make sure Secure Boot is off. The process always go successfully, it warns you that you need to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Yeah, I also checked the BIOS before starting the process, it's definitely disabled. EDIT: I've also attached a link to my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, as I heard that may be of some use.